# Hamiltonian energy density, energy flux, and Poisson brackets

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, energy-conservation, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian

I came across an old paper (Hardy, *Energy Flux Operator for a Lattice*. Physical Review. Volume 132 Number 1, 1963) that states a relation between the time rate of energy density, the "energy density operator", and the Hamiltonian.

Hardy basically begins the paper with:

[image]

Equation 2.1 is simply energy continuity, saying that the time rate of energy density of a material element is equal to the spatial change in flux through that element.

What is Equation 2.2 and why is it true? I've never seen a Poisson bracket with an "energy density operator" and a Hamiltonian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the equation of time evolution of the operator $H(\vec{x})$ in the [Heisenberg picture](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_picture). This is another formulation of QM where the Schrödinger equation is replaced with
$$ \frac{dA(t)}{dt} = \frac{i}{\hbar} [H, A(t)] $$
for any operator $A$.

In this case, I imagine that the total Hamiltonian would be given by $H = \int d^3 x\, H(\vec{x}, t)$, so you could go on to write it as
$$ \dot{H}(\vec{x}, t) = \frac{i}{\hbar} \int d^3 y\, [H(\vec{y}, t), H(\vec{x}, t)] $$
which looks interesting!